# Unstable formulas

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

A formula $\phi(x,y)$ has the order property if the are $(a_i)_{i<\omega}$ and $(b_j)_{j<\omega}$  such that $$ i< j \,\,\,\,\, \,\, \text{iff} \,\,\,\,\, \,\,  \models \phi(a_i, b_j).$$
A theory $T$ is called stable if there is no formula with the order property.

Is the theory of graphs stable?

Comment: What is the definition of an unstable formula?

Comment: What have you tried? Also your question is not really precise. Assuming that by "unstable formula" you mean "formula with the order property", the question still does not make sense because you have not specified a theory. You only specify the language, but what theory do you mean?

Comment: To put Mark's point another way: "there are [$a$'s and $b$'s]" in the definition means that these $a$'s and $b$'s exist in some model of some fixed theory $T$. Until you specify $T$, the question makes no sense, because it's not clear where the $a$'s and $b$'s should come from.

Comment: I modified my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the theory of graphs is not stable.

Consider the graph with elements $\{a_i,b_i\mid i\in \omega\}$ and edge relation $R$, where $a_iRb_j$ if and only if $i<j$. This shows that the formula $xRy$ has the order property relative to the theory of graphs.

Comment: What is the theory of graphs in the classification of first order theories? Is it simple or NIP or ......?

Comment: @Joe368 It's a theorem (you can find a proof in Hodges's big *Model Theory*) that for any structure $A$ in a finite language, there is some graph $G_A$ which interprets $A$. As a consequence, the theory of graphs has every "bad" classification-theoretic property. The intuition is that the theory of graphs doesn't say very much - it is badly incomplete, in that it does very little to pin down behavior of its models, so it's no surprise that it has very "wild" models.

Comment: On the other hand, one can argue that when faced with a badly incomplete theory, we should instead study its *model companion*. This is what we do when we move from studying arbitrary fields (very wild) to studying algebraically closed fields (very tame). The model companion of the theory of graphs is the theory of the random graph, which is simple (supersimple of rank 1 with trivial forking) and  has the independence property.